# how to take a whole candle into consideration

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

```
strategy("My script",overlay=true)
cad = close[0]

top = high[0]

tail = low[0]

ema = ta.ema(close,15)

plot(ema)

start = timestamp(2022,1,1,0,0,0)

end = timestamp(2022,6,1,0,0,0)    

if time>=start and time<=end

   if top>ema and tail<ema

       strategy.entry("short",strategy.short,100)

       buy_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1)

       strategy.close("short",when=buy_price*1.00)
```

hi, i want to single out the candle which does not touch the EMA 15 line the candle can be absolutely above or absolutely below ,but it should not touch the EMA line. How can I do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOnmo.png)

Comment: @vitruvius, hi will you take a look into my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `high` is lower than `ema`, than the whole candle is lower than the `ema`, and if `low` is higher than `ema` than the candle is above the `ema`.

Therefor you can check those conditions in order to get all the candles which do not touch the ema line:

```
if high < ema or low > ema
    // do something
```